# custom baggage key not showing up in logs with Spring cloud sleuth

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

Not seeing custom baggage id in the spring boot micro-service logs. 
Below are the steps followed.
 1. Used spring-cloud-starter-sleuth 2.2.1.release with springboot 2.2.0. Snippet from pom-
        `<parent> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>

        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version> 
        <relativePath/> 
        <!-- lookup parent from repository --> 
       </parent> 
    <dependencies>
        <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId> 
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version> 
    </dependency>`

2. Both properties in application.propertieswhere set as:

   ```
   spring.sleuth.baggage-keys=baggage-TraceId

   spring.sleuth.log.slf4j.whitelisted-mdc-keys=baggage-TraceId.
   ```
3. logback-spring.xml is set with this baggage-TraceId.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   ```

   ```
   <springProperty scope="context" name="springName" source="spring.application.name" defaultValue=""/>
   <!-- You can override this to have a custom pattern -->
   <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN"
             value="%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(%5p [${springName},%X{traceId:-},%X{parentId:-},%X{spanId:-},%X{baggage-TraceId:-}]) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%t]){faint}  %clr(%logger{20}:%line){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}"/>

   <!-- Logging configuration -->
   <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
       <encoder>
           <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
       </encoder>
   </appender>
      <root level="INFO">
           <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
           <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
       </root>
   ```
4. in Filter, set the header value fetched from the service request.

   ```
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain 
   filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

   log.info("In Filter-START");

   ExtraFieldPropagation.set("baggage-TraceId","1234");

   log.info("In Filter-END"+ExtraFieldPropagation.get("baggage-TraceId"));
   ```

   }

Comment: Can you show how you're using sleuth?

Comment: Here is the code from pom and logback-spring.xml:
<parent> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version> <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository --> </parent> <dependencies><dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId> <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version> </dependency>

Comment: Please update your question with this info i can't read code from a comment

Comment: Updated question with info.